# What GRE verbal score is needed for a non-native English speaker to get into math or applied math PhD programs in the USA?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, mathematics

I am an international student whose native language is not English. I am planning to apply for a Phd program in math or applied math in US in the future and general GRE test is a requirement.

From most posts [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/43570/which-one-have-more-importance-to-us-phd-program-toefl-and-gre-or-publication-r/43577#43577), I know I should put more attention in related research experience and GRE test only matters when it's low. But I am wondering what it means exactly. I know most universities have a minimum score for TOEFL speaking session but didn't find any information about GRE general test.

My classmates told me that based on previous record, in order to get admitted by a top program (top10 or 20), both verbal (V) and quantitative (Q) can't be bad. For Q I should aim at 140 but they are not sure about V. I also checked some forums such as mathgre. I found a lot of local applicants got verbal score higher than 135. To achieve that, I must put a lot of effort which will reduce my time about research significantly.

Hence I want to know what kind of gre general score is acceptable for international applicants who plan to apply for top theoretical phd programs? Based on my understanding, most programs usually higher GRE subject score for international students, will you usually have different language requirements for local/international students (except toefl) when you review the application materials?

Comment: @jakebeal I don't think that is a duplicate. I am focussing on what it means by "low gre" and whether there is difference between gre requirements of international students and local students. Hence I don't think it answers my question.

Comment: I'm not sure that any general answer exists, as different universities are likely to weight their judgements differently.

Comment: Just to add a data point, in my old field (quantitative but not math) the GRE verbal was disregarded. Of the other two, one (quantitative) served as a cutoff (at the school I ended up, below 90%, and you were out). The other factored into your admission as an also-ran. Sufficient English proficiency was deduced from your TOEFL, but - based on some of my classmates - this cannot have been very strict. If your writing style in your question represents your English, I wouldn't sweat it. My field didn't require a GRE subject.